# jQuery add class to next list item one at a time AND loop back to beginning

Tags: jquery, pagination, carousel, listitem

I have created a jQuery circular carousel that loops through x amounts of slides. I have been adding pagination to this slider. Each point is a list item that relates to each slide. When slide number one is visible, li number one has the class current. When you click next, the class is removed from li number one and added to li number 2.

The issue I have is that once I have gone through all of the list items, I want the class "current" to be added back to the first list item - the oppsite also needs to happen when the previous button is clicked.

Here is my jQuery code for the pagination:

```
window.next = function() {
var li = jQuery("li.current");
if (li.length)
    li.removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
else
    jQuery("li").first().addClass("current");
}
window.prev = function() {
var li = jQuery("li.current");
if (li.length)
    li.removeClass("current").prev().addClass("current");
else
    jQuery("li").last().addClass("current");
}
}
```

and my html markup:

```
<ul>
<li class="current"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone tell me how I get this to loop around?
You can see my work here http://www.samskirrow.com/projects/carousel

Comment: Getting closer with answers below. Here is a JSfiddle with my current working. Still not looping. http://jsfiddle.net/uaULj/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check if `next` exists, and if it doesn't, you must be at the end, so pick the first:

```
if (li.length){

    var $next = li.next();

    if($next.length == 0) $next = $("li").first();

    li.removeClass("current");
    $next.addClass("current");
}
```

And similarly for prev.

Comment: Works for the back arrow - not for forward arrow for some reason. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uaULj/14/

Comment: The isue was that the "current" class was adding itself to another ul on the page after the last li in the pagination. Got around it by removing that list.

Comment: You might consider adding a class to your `li` elements or to the `ul` which contains them to narrow your selectors.  That way there will be no conflict if there are other `li` elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.next = function() {
   var li = jQuery("li.current");
   if (li.length && li.next().length)
       li.removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
   else {
       li.removeClass("current");
       jQuery("li").first().addClass("current");
   }
}

window.prev = function() {
   var li = jQuery("li.current");
   if (li.length && li.prev().length)
       li.removeClass("current").prev().addClass("current");
   else {
       li.removeClass("current");
       jQuery("li").last().addClass("current");
   }
}
```

Comment: Only issue is that this would not remove the class from `current`.  You can move the `removeClass` into the `if` condition or even the variable assignment.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't seem to work. Still the same issue with the class changing for the three list items, but not looping back around

Comment: For me it's looping around, when i click next in your last image it gets to the first..

Comment: Make sure you refresh your browser, it could be a cache thing.

Comment: Very weird, cleared browsing history and reset browser and still not really working. Are you able to draw up a quick jsfiddle??

Comment: What browser are you on? here FF 19